# need initfamfs modules. 15.04

Tags: boot, drivers, 15.04, ubuntu-gnome

is anything else supposed to be here? I am using Ubuntu gnome and my keyboard is unresponsive for encryption password. Do I need any more modules, and if so where do I add them.

```
# List of modules that you want to include in your initramfs.
# They will be loaded at boot time in the order below.
#
# Syntax:  module_name [args ...]
#
# You must run update-initramfs(8) to effect this change.
#
# Examples:
#
# raid1
# sd_mod
```